# Dynamic load of DataTemplates

Tags: c#, desktop-application, avaloniaui, avalonia

How can I provide data templates dynamically from code?

I have view model MainWindowViewModel that I bind to MainWindow. It looks like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

        public int Progress
        {
            get => _progress;
            set => RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _progress, value);
        }

        public ViewModelBase? Content
        {
            get => _content;
            set => RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _content, value);
        }
}
```

then in the MainWindow I chose DataTemplate based on a type tied to my MainWindowViewModel

```
<ContentControl Name="Header" Content="{Binding Content}">
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DefaultViewModel}">
        <local:DefaultView></local:DefaultView>
     </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
```

It is currently only a single DataTemplate but I would like to load it from different places so I'm trying to replace it with dynamically generated list of DataTemplates as in the future, some control I will need to load from external file provided by user.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `IDataTemplate` implementation and forward calls to the actual template dynamically. E. g. ViewLocator from Avalonia MVVM template looks like this:

```cs
    public class ViewLocator : IDataTemplate
    {
        public IControl Build(object data)
        {
            var name = data.GetType().FullName!.Replace("ViewModel", "View");
            var type = Type.GetType(name);

            if (type != null)
            {
                return (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(type)!;
            }
            else
            {
                return new TextBlock { Text = "Not Found: " + name };
            }
        }

        public bool Match(object data)
        {
            return data is ViewModelBase;
        }
    }
```